# How can I convert CSS From Figma to Flutter?

Tags: css, flutter, figma

I work with Figma and I need to create a button with the next CSS properties

```
background: #FFA01F;
box-shadow: inset 12px -9px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
border-radius: 100px;
```

Comment: show us figma photo tu understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use Container as replacement for button, and use `BoxDecoration` to create something similiar to it.

```
 Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: const Color(#FFA01F),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          boxShadow: [
             BoxShadow(
               color: Colors.red,
               blurRadius: 2,
               offset: Offset(2, 4),  //position               
              )
          ]
     ),
  )
```

Comment: I did it already but I can't figure out how to define the box shadow properties

Comment: I put an example for Box Shadow properties, maybe you can try to read the documentation for more information.